# импорт XML с кириллицей в SQL

Tags: xml, sql

Добрый день. Мне необходимо импортировать в SQL XML-файл со значениями на русском.

Пример XML:

```
<data_exchange data_type="документы" config_name="Магазин" date_creation="2012-08-15" time_creation="18:14:57">

<goods_item>
...some data...
</goods_item>

</data_exchange>
```

SQL-запрос:

```
declare @insert nvarchar(4000), @pathname varchar(200), @xml xml
set @pathname = 'file_path'
create table #tmp_xml(xmldata xml)
set @insert = 'INSERT INTO #tmp_xml(xmldata) SELECT bulkcolumn 
      FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N''' + @pathname+ ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS data'
exec sp_executesql @insert
select @xml = xmldata from #tmp_xml
INSERT INTO store_XML_import
SELECT 
Tbl.Col.value('my_data', 'type'),
FROM @xml.nodes('/data_exchange/goods_item') Tbl(Col)

drop table #tmp_xml
```

Анализатор выдает ошибку на 27 символе 1 строки - букве "д". В XML указывал кодировки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Пробовал Windows-1251, то же самое. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` означает, что кодировка собственно самого XML должна быть UTF-8. Скорее всего у вас кодировка файла не совпадает с декларированной кодировкой - поэтому и ругается парсер